# Converting string to int in serial connection

Tags: python, serial-port

I am trying to read a line from serial connection and convert it to int:

```
print arduino.readline()
length = int(arduino.readline())
```

but getting this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I looked up this error and means that it is not possible to convert an empty string to int, but the thing is, my `readline` is not empty, because it prints it out.

Comment: what's the output of `print arduino.readline()`?

Comment: The problem is when you call `readline()` in `print` it consumes the contents and therefore successive call will be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `print` statement prints it out and the next call reads the next line. You should probably do.

```
num = arduino.readline()
length = int(num)
```

Since you mentioned that the Arduino is returning C style strings, you should strip the NULL character.

```
num = arduino.readline()
length = int(num.strip('\0'))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
print arduino.readline()
```

you have already read the currently available line. So, the next `readline` might not be getting any data. You might want to store this in a variable like this

```
data = arduino.readline()
print data
length = int(data)
```

As the data seems to have null character (`\0`) in it, you might want to strip that like this

```
data = arduino.readline().rstrip('\0')
```

Comment: I am getting now  this error= `ValueError: null byte in argument for int()`. Do I need to add a null byte character at the end ?

Comment: @pattex007 What does the `print` statement print?

Comment: @pattex007: Strip the null character. `data.strip('\0')`. Arduino returns C style strings, I think.

Comment: this is the code for sending data `uartPutData( "16", sizeof(FINAL_LENGTH));` and for output: 16

Comment: @pattex007 Just try the suggestion given by Sukrit

Answer (score 1):

Every call to readline() reads a new line, so your first statement has read a line already, next time you call readline() data is not available anymore.

Try this:

```
s = arduino.readline()
if len(s) != 0:
    print s
    length = int(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when the arduino starts to send serial data it starts by sending empty strings initially, so the pyserial picks up an empty string `''` which cannot be converted to an integer. You can add a delay above `serial.readline()`, like this:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1.5)
    pos = arduino.readline().rstrip().decode()
    print(pos)
```